# Jon Erickson's book - bootable CD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8.1, 64-bit, operating-systems

Jon Erickson's interesting [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593271441) on hacking contains a bootable Ubuntu linux-based CD that has preconfigured environment that would help the reader apply the code examples in the book. However, the CD required a x86 computer (not 64 bits) and most of the PCs around are 64 bits.

Is there a way one could still boot into and use such a bootable CD on a 64 bits machine without losing any features or functionality (as intended)?

Comment: x86-64, is *still* x86.

Comment: Or in other words, every 64bit x86 CPU so far can also run in 32bit mode, if necessary. Did you actually try to boot the CD?

Comment: @dirkt Hi, yes, I adjusted the BIOS setting to boot from CD, and I can see it tries to read it upon startup, but it fails. I read somewhere that other people could not run it on 64 bits, so I thought this could be the reason.

Comment: Have you tried Virtualbox?

Comment: The book is from 2008, so I do suspect UEFI or "doesn't know how to switch to 32 bit mode" issues. Definitely try Virtualbox, QEMU etc.

Comment: Can you boot another CD?  Verify it can actually boot from ANY bootable CD.

Comment: @Damon I don't have any other bootable CD to hand. How about converting the bootable CD to bootable USB drive (as in here: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-convert-a-bootable-cd-to-a-bootable-usb)? Would that work?

Comment: @Mokubai How should I use VirtualBox for this case? I want to run the CD and not install a guest OS, would Virtualbox do that? I don't know how the author have preconfigured the environment in the CD version, and I'd prefer using it rather than a standard distribution.

Comment: Just point Virtualbox at the CD (or an ISO you created of the CD) and set it running. You shouldn't need to install another OS, it should boot the CD as if it were a real computer booting it.

Comment: @Mokubai I tried it with VirtualBox as you said, and it booted the live CD from DVD Drive, but then after the welcome screen, when I chose to start the Live CD, it froze on "Loading, please  wait...". I then tried it again with an ISO file for the Live CD, and again, it froze at the same sentence. Not sure what is wrong. Here is the ISO file, in case you want to see for yourself: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qstyx8yqpuz8rgl/Erickson%20book%20LiveCD.iso?dl=0

Comment: The bundled CD contains a forefather of the current Kali Linux distro. Better to download and use the current release. The commands are the same. The problem is not 32-bit, it's the lack of support for UEFI booting. And it's ridiculous to use anything from 10 years ago anyway.

Comment: @MichaelBay I don't mind using a newer distribution that follows the old one. But is that all what the author meant by "preconfigured" environment? Or would there be (if I used the newer Kali distribution) any missing settings that the authored had fixed to make the book material/examples run okay for beginners? Yes, it is a bit old, but it is fun and a nice book. It would be nice if I could get the CD to work.

Comment: The "preconfigured" environment is just a Linux distro with certain pentest/penetration and forensic tools already installed (that's what means "preconfigured"). They're roughly the same as always and can also be installed in any other distro, even standard Debian/Ubuntu (the thing used in 2008 was actually based on Ubuntu whereas the current Kali is based on Debian).

Comment: @MichaelBay Is there a way I can find out what were the "preconfigured" things that that authored had fixed in the old environment, so that I can install Kali distro instead, as you suggested, and add these configurations, so I can work with the book under a newer distro?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way one could still boot into and use such a bootable CD on a 64 bits machine without losing any features or functionality (as intended)?

As pointed out in the comments, [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) could be a simple solution.

> How should I use VirtualBox for this case? I want to run the CD and not install a guest OS, would Virtualbox do that?

Yes, it should be able to do that. Assuming that your disk is a [live CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) or similar, hardware emulation should be all that is required (live CDs do not need installation, though some may offer it). That is, you would create a virtual machine as normal (Ubuntu 32-bit albeit likely without a virtual HDD) and simply attach a virtual CD drive that you would boot the VM directly from with your disk (this could be an ISO of the CD or be attached to a real drive on the PC which would read the physical disk).